# How to show pieces into the another pieces?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have two type of pieces one is **Authors** and second one is **Articles**. I can  show the list of articles (by using `indexAjax.html` and `index.html` in `articles-pages`) as it is implemented in Apostrophe's [Demo](http://demo.apostrophecms.org) and the list of Authors as well (by using `indexAjax.html` and `index.html` in `authors-pages/views`).

My question is how can I show the articles written by some specified author in by using `show.html` file of `authors-pages/views` ?
So when user clicks on some author he/she should be able to see the list of articles written by the specified author.

The `lib/modules/articles/index.js` file is the following

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    name: 'articles',
    label: 'Article',
    pluralLabel: 'Articles',
    contextual: true,
    addFields: [
        {
            name: '_author',
            type: 'joinByOne',
            withType: 'author',
            label: 'Author',
            idField: 'author',
            filters: {
                projection: {
                    title: 1,
                    slug: 1,
                    type: 1,
                    tags: 1
                }
            }
        },

....

    ]

};
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Karlen, use the joinByArray [guide](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#code-join-by-array-code) as a starting point.

Comment: Hi @robert-jakobson, thanks for your comment. I have already find a solution. I didn't want to use `joingByArray` because once any article created the id of article should be added into that list, hence it will bring one to one linking between db docs which I think is not good idea for this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the architect of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

The code in your own solution effectively reimplements a feature we already have: reverse joins.

You already have a "forward" join (`joinByOne`). So use `joinByOneReverse` to make those items available from the "other side."

In the schema for **authors**, you can write this:

```
addFields: [
  {
    name: '_articles',
    type: 'joinByOneReverse',
    withType: 'articles',
    label: 'Articles',
    idField: 'author',
    filters: {
      projection: {
        title: 1,
        slug: 1,
        type: 1,
        tags: 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This makes a `._articles` array property available on each author.

It is important to note that `idField` doesn't change. We are intentionally using the same information so that we get the same content.

If you wish, you can also set `ifOnlyOne: true` on that field to avoid having it fetched for the index page and other contexts where you load more than one author.

Check out the [guide to schemas](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked almost the all pages of documentation, but didn't realized this option or forgot that, or maybe I have overlooked the docs. Anyway thanks for the great platform and for your answer as well!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer for my own question (before seeing the posted alternative answer). Hope it will be useful for others.

So there are two pieces `articles` and `authors`.

**lib/modules/authors-pages/index.js**

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
    articlesPerPage: 3,
    construct: function (self, options) {
        var beforeShow = self.beforeShow;
        self.beforeShow = function (req, callback) {
            var limit = self.options.articlesPerPage;
            var skip = req.query.page || 1;
            skip = (parseInt(skip) - 1) * limit;
            if (!req.data || !req.data.piece) {
                return beforeShow(req, callback);
            }
            var cursor = self.apos.docs.getManager('articles').find(req, {
                author: req.data.piece._id
            });
            cursor
                .skip(skip)
                .limit(limit)
                .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
                .toArray(function (err, articles) {
                    req.data._articles = articles || [];
                    req.data.currentPage = Math.ceil((skip + 1) / limit);
                    cursor.toCount(function(err, count){
                        if(err)
                            count = 1;
                        req.data.totalPages = Math.ceil(count / limit);
                        beforeShow(req, callback);
                    })

                })
        }
    }
}
```

**lib/modules/authors-pages/view/show.html**

```
{% extends data.outerLayout %} 
{% block title %}
    {{ data.piece.title }}
{% endblock %} 
{% block main %}
    {% for article in data._articles %}
        <p>{{article.title}}</p>    
    {% endfor %}
    {% import 'apostrophe-pager:macros.html' as pager with context %}
    {{ pager.render({ page: data.currentPage, total: data.totalPages }, data.url) }}
{% endblock %}
```