# joinByOneReverse data not showing

Tags: apostrophe-cms

this is a partial continuation of the following question: [How to show pieces into the another pieces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689975/how-to-show-pieces-into-the-another-pieces) and another one that I accidentally deleted, but got a lot of help on (thanks!)

I have the following module blogTag that I want to connect via the `joinByOneReverse` field with pieces of the apostrophe blog module and pieces created by me "work" and "inspiration". It´s here index.js:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'blogTag',
  label: 'Blog Tag',
  pluralLabel: 'Blog Tags',
  addFields: [
    {
        name: 'title',
        label: 'Title',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    {
        name: 'intro',
        label: 'Introduction',
        type: 'area',
        options: {
            widgets: {
                'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                    controls: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink']
                },
                'apostrophe-images': {}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'icon',
        label: 'Icon',
        type: 'singleton',
        widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
        options: {
            limit: 1
        }
    },
    {
      name: '_workName',
      type: 'joinByOneReverse',
      withType: 'work',
      label: 'Work',
      idField: 'blogTagId',
      filters: {
        projection: {
          title: 1,
          slug: 1,
          type: 1,
          tags: 1
        }
      }
    },
    { 
      name: '_inspirationName',
      type: 'joinByOneReverse',
      withType: 'inspiration',
      label: 'Inspiration',
      idField: 'blogTagInspirationId',
      filters: {
        projection: {
          title: 1,
          slug: 1,
          type: 1,
          tags: 1
        }
      }
    },
     {
      name: '_blogTagArticleName',
      type: 'joinByOneReverse',
      withType: 'apostrophe-blog',
      label: 'Blog Article',
      idField: 'blogTagArticleId',
      filters: {
        projection: {
          title: 1,
          slug: 1,
          type: 1,
          tags: 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]


}
```

and as an example for the "work" piece I have the following module with the following index.js  module in a "b2b-portfolio" folder:

```
module.exports = {
   extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
   name: 'work',
   label: 'Work',
   pluralLabel: 'Works',
   addFields: [
    {
        name: 'title',
        label: 'Title',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    {
        name: 'intro',
        label: 'Introduction',
        type: 'area',
        options: {
            widgets: {
                'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                    controls: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink']
                },
                'apostrophe-images': {}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'screenshot',
        label: 'Screenshot',
        type: 'singleton',
        widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
        options: {
            limit: 1,
            minSize: [ 800, 800 ],
            aspectRatio: [ 1, 1]
        }
    },
      {
         name: '_blogTag',
         type: 'joinByOne',
         withType: 'blogTag',
         label: 'Blog Tag',
         idField: 'blogTagId',
         filters: {
            projection: {
               title: 1,
               slug: 1,
               type: 1,
               tags: 1
            }
         }
      },
      {
        name: 'publishedAt',
        label: 'Publishing date',
        type: 'date'
      }
   ]
 }
```

However, in the module "b2b-blog-tags-pages" the following in show.html views does not output the expected data:

```
{% for work in data._workName %}
       <h2><a href="{{ work._url }}">{{ work.title }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

EDIT: The following did not work either:

```
{% for work in data.piece._workName %}
       <h2><a href="{{ work._url }}">{{ work.title }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Here are the MongoDB documents from the aposDocs collection as an example:

[image]

and..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The property is attached to each piece. In show.html that would mean data.piece._workName.

Comment: ` {% for work in data.piece._workName %} 
                                <h2><a href="{{ work._url }}">{{ work.title }}</a></h2>
 {% endfor %} `  - hhm, that did not work

Comment: That should work. At this point I think it would make the most sense for you to reproduce this in a fork of our sandbox project or other project you can share on github.